# How do I return a different value from a stub based on a lambda argument

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I have the following sample test code

```
    public Stage Test(Stage Stage)
    {
        var StartStage = StageRepository.Single(x => x.Order == 1);
        var EndStage = StageRepository.Single(x => x.Order == 5);
        var ErrorStage = StageRepository.Single(x => x.Name == "Error");

        if (Stage == StartStage)
        {
            return EndStage;
        }
        else
        {
            return ErrorStage;
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to test it using the following unit test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void XXXTest()
    {
        //// Arrange
        var AutoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<StageService>(MockMode.AAA);

        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();

        var MockStageRepository = AutoMocker.Get<IRepository<Stage>>();

        Stage StartStage = mockRepository.Stub<Stage>();
        StartStage.Order = 1;

        Stage EndStage = mockRepository.Stub<Stage>();
        EndStage.Order = 5;

        Stage ErrorStage = mockRepository.Stub<Stage>();
        ErrorStage.Name = "Error";

        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>> StartParam = x => x.Order == 1;
        MockStageRepository
            .Stub(x => x.Single(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>>>.Is.Equal(StartParam)))
            .Return(StartStage);

        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>> EndParam = x => x.Order == 1;
        MockStageRepository
            .Stub(x => x.Single(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>>>.Is.Equal(EndParam)))
            .Return(EndStage);

        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>> ErrorParam = x => x.Order == 1;
        MockStageRepository
            .Stub(x => x.Single(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>>>.Is.Equal(ErrorParam)))
            .Return(ErrorStage);

        StageService StageService = AutoMocker.ClassUnderTest;


        //Act
        var ReturnStage = StageService.Test(StartStage);


        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(ReturnStage, EndStage);
    }
```

However this is not working as it is not returning anything when I call StageRepository.Single(). If I change the stub code to ignore the argument then it does return something but it will be the same object returned for each call to Single() which I don't want.

Is it possible to configure RhinoMocks in such a way as to return different objects from a stub depending on the lambda that is passed into it?

Comment: Sorry what is `RhinoAutoMocker`?

Comment: `RhinoAutoMocker` is part of StructureMap and just creates simple test objects with all its dependancies pre mocked for you.

Comment: Mike - is it just a typo that the second setup line also returns StartStage and not EndStage?

Comment: Sorry Lee, that was a typo, now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that equality on the `Expression<Func<T,U>>` type is performed by reference rather than value. That means your telling Rhino Mocks to look for instances of expressions created in the test rather than the ones created in the code your testing.

Two possible approaches come to mind:

- One would be to provide a way to pass the lambda expressions in to the Stage class from the test, so that when the argument checks happen they are working against the same instances.

  Maybe something like:

  ```
  internal void SetStartStage(Expression<Func<Entities.Stage,bool>> predicate)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

  The inverse of this would also work, i.e. provide the `Expression` objects as   fields/properties that can be accessed by you're test, and then use those when setting up your mock:

  ```
  internal Expression<Func<Entities.State,bool>> StartStagePredicate
  {
      get{ return x => x.Order == 1; }
  }
  ```
- Another option would be to use the `Matches` method on `Args` to see if the argument checks the `Stage` object state correctly.  This would require creating some `Stage` objects in your test that would match the criteria:

  ```
  var startStageTester = new Stage { Order = 1 };
  MockStageRepository
          .Stub(x => x.Single(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>>>.Matches(y => y.Compile()(startStageTester)))
          .Return(StartStage);
  ```

  The call to `Compile()` is a little jarring, but since you're dealing with an Expression and not a straight-up lambda, you've got to compile it in order to evaluate it.

  Now, if a `Stage` is something that is hard to create, then you may need to create a Mock/Stub of one (or use you're `StartStage`) and have it return 1 from the `Order` property (in the case of the StartStage anyway).

There are probably some others I'm not thinking of at the moment as well.

Answer (score 1):

IF the linq condition is not important, I would propose to match it as any, something like this

```
repository.Stub(x => x.Find(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>.Is.Anything)).Return(entitiesList.AsQueryable());
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. That worked a treat. The one thing that I was missing was the `Compile` method on an ExpressionTree. There is a small bug in your sample code (you use x twice). For completeness here is the working code.

```
        MockStageRepository2
            .Stub(x => x.Single(Arg<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entities.Stage, bool>>>.Matches(y => y.Compile()(StartStage2))))
            .Return(StartStage2);
```